# How to create triangle and use it as a arrow in tooltip

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make some custom tooltip using html and CSS. The main problem, what I have is with arrow styles.

The result is more or less as I wanted, but I can't believe that I need to set this values, like: right, top etc. pixel by pixel. There is maybe more elegant way to do this?

```css
body {
  background: #de302f;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  top: 100%;
  right: -26.9px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -25px;
  background: #de302f;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 73px;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  top: 24px;
  right: -52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use an SVG but otherwise I think your solution works perfectly so I'm not sure what the issue is? You do need to tweak your values a bit and I wouldn't use decimals on pixels.

Comment: @isherwood Maybe it is not a problem. But to get this solution, I had to set pixel by pixel (add in one place, then subtract in another, so only then everything fits perfectly). So that's is a little bit weird, and I I thought I do something wrong

Comment: If your problem is that you feel like you're fighting with the technology to get it to do something it wasn't meant for... then yes, I'd say that's exactly what you are doing. `box-sizing: border-box` might help you, but I'd also recommend using SVG instead of CSS hacks if you're trying to draw complex shapes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/tdh0bfcw/ Here's an example of an SVG I put together real quick. If you're really concerned with getting the perfect shape, I'd go with an SVG instead of pseudo-elements. You can learn more about them at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

Comment: Yes, it's look amazing, but as I said, I need to change styles for antd tooltip component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify a little like below:

```css
body {
  background: #de302f;
}

.container {
  --t: 2px; /* thickness */
  --b: var(--t) solid #fff; /* border here */
  
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: var(--b);
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 -100vmax);
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: 40px; /* control the height here */
  right: calc(-1*var(--t));
  border-right: var(--b);
}
.container:after {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: var(--b);
  transform: skewX(30deg); /* control the angle here */
  transform-origin: 0 calc(100% - var(--t));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Really nice. I like to include links to resources for the more advanced CSS features. Even as an experienced front-end developer they're not always front-of-mind.

Comment: @Temani Afif could you look on this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/colorful-tooltip-antd-4-21-0-forked-bre16f?file=/demo.js I have tried to follow yours code and implement this using tooltip from antd library. Am I missing something? Cuz it is not so perfect fit like in your example ;/ There is small white break

Comment: @HarryP it looks good to me, where do you see the white break?

Comment: @TemaniAfif white break I fixed with border-radius: 0. You can see the corner of the arrow is a bit too long, I don't know why

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am really need your sharp eye :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added box-sizing: initial to before and after and it look good