# How to style tooltip from antd library

Tags: css, styles, tooltip, antd

Few hours ago, I asked, how can I implement triangle as an arrow in a tooltip.

I got perfect answer which is here:

[How to create triangle and use it as a arrow in tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562575/how-to-create-triangle-and-use-it-as-a-arrow-in-tooltip/72563076#72563076)

Now I am working on tooltip from `antd` library. Arrow in this tooltip is not look quite as I want to. I would like to style this same as in the previous question - as in the link above.

Here's the link to codebox where I tried to style tooltip from `antd` library using code from the previous question - as in the link above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/colorful-tooltip-antd-4-21-0-forked-bre16f?file=/demo.js

The problem:

As you can see the corner of the arrow is a bit too long, there are white gaps at the lower border. Nothing like that happens in the previous example. Everything is perfectly fit there

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the arrow as pointed below.

```
  .ant-tooltip-inner:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
height: 12px; /* <=======control the height here */
right: calc(-1 * var(--t));
border-right: var(--b);
box-sizing: initial;
```

}

I didn't get the white gaps at the lower borders. Can you point it out with an image/screenshot?